# How to implement two different Splash screen in ios schemas?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, schema, splash-screen

I have a flutter application where flavor is implemented and splash screen works fine in android but in ios it takes the default splash screen always. How to set different splash screens for different schemas having two different package names? Any idea?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope @Muhammed Refaat , I set the splashscreen from xcode UI manually when uploading or running the app which serves my purpose.

Comment: Aha I see ......